# When to use __declspec(noalias)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, strict-aliasing

As I understood if (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noalias?view=vs-2019) `__declspec(noalias)` means that the function only modifies memory inside her body or through the parameters, so its not modifying static variables, or memory throught double pointers, is that correct?

```cpp
static int g = 3;

class Test
{
   int x;

  Test& __declspec(noalias) operator +(const int b) //is noalias correct?
  {
    x += b;
    return *this;
  }

  void __declspec(noalias) test2(int& x) { //correct here?
   x = 3;
  }

  void __declspec(noalias) test3(int** x) { //not correct here!?

   *x = 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given something like:

```
extern int x;
extern int bar(void);

int foo(void)
{
  if (x)
    bar();
  return x;
}
```

a compiler that knows nothing about `bar()` would need to generate code that allows for the possibility that it might change the value of `x`, and would thus have to load the value of `x` both before and after the function call.  While some systems use so-called "link time optimization" to defer code generation of a function until after any function it calls have been analyzed to see what external objects, if any, they might access, MS uses a simpler approach of simply allowing function prototypes to say that they don't access any outside objects which the calling code might want to cache.  This is a crude approach, but allows compilers to reap low hanging fruit cheaply and easily.